# exported Wordpress website and now my css and js don't load

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404

When trying to export my wordpress website to a different computer, my css, js and image files don't load anny more.

everything worked prefect on my other computer.

I did try the follow:

1. check my username and password on phpmyadmin and wp-config
2. used the correct wp-prefix
3. deactived all my wp plugins
4. correctly installed my sql database again
5. check database name in wp-config

Now i get this error message in the browsers console:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 1):

Hello Sebastian Tramper,

May be you are trying to migrate your project to one computer to another.

Also when you migrate remember, there should be same development environment setup done. I mean you can use wamp or xampp for it.

Then you just keep **foldername same** for both computer. For wamp you will put it in www and for xampp , you need to put it in htdocs.

Then you just keep the **same db name** and import db what is you exported in other computer.

If you want to free from this hassle and use a different folder name. For this you can use duplication.

Here is a tutorial how you can use duplicator : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6oQIH1S6Qw

Plugin link : https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

Thanks, if you have more question let me know.